# Why does calling "ion()" hide my plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib

The following code produces a completely blank window, no errors, just a blank window:

```
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>> plt.ion()
>>> fig=plt.figure()
>>> ax=fig.add_subplot(111)
>>> ax.plot((0,1),(1,0))
[<matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x112654e50>]
>>> plt.show()
>>> fig.show()
```

AFAICT tell, the `plt.ion()` call creates this problem somehow.  Can I somehow set interactive on and still work with subplots, axes, etc.?

EDIT: When I run from inside PyCharm, everything is fine.  It is using the same python that I use from the command line.  Does this sound like a system problem?  I am working on Mac OS X El Capitan.  Ring any bells?

Comment: I copied your code and it work fine for me. Which version of python are you using? By the way `plt.show` shows all figures that are being plotted so there's no need to put `fig.show` at the end.

Comment: If you think `plt.ion` is the problem, what happens if you get rid of it from your code?

Comment: @DavidG If I remove plt.ion, everything works just fine.  I put the "show" commands in as a failed attempt to force python to display the plot.  I'm using 2.7.

Comment: @DavidG Please see edit to my question.

Comment: is the same python interpreter / virtual environment being used from within pycharm and without

Comment: It sounds like it has something to do with the system yes. I am by no means an expert and even less so when it comes to macs. Is there a reason why you want to use the command line and not PyCharm?